# Algorithm to find maximum possible value of the minimum expression in a list

Tags: reference-request, optimization, algorithms

**Problem**

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m \in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose I have a bunch of expressions which are linear combinations of $1, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m$.  For example, I might have
\begin{align*}
& x_1 + 3x_3 - 4 \\
& x_2 + x_3 \\
& x_4 \\
& x_1 - x_4 + x_5 - x_6 \\
& \cdots \\
& x_m + 5
\end{align*}

I am interested in finding an algorithm or method which determines the **supremum** over all $x_1, \ldots, x_m \in \mathbb{R}$ of the **minimum** of these expressions.  (Note that in the cases I'm interested in, the supremum will be achieved, i.e., it will be a maximum.)

**Example**

As an example in three variables, the expressions might be

\begin{align*}
& x \\
& y \\
& z \\
& 3 - x \\
& 3 - y \\
& 3 - z \\
& 5 - x - y \\
& x + y - 2 \\
& 7 - x - y - z \\
& x + y + z - 4 \\
\end{align*}

In this case, you can work out that since $(3-x) + (3-y) + (3-z) + (x + y + z - 4) = 5$, one of the expressions must be at most $5/4$.  Indeed, $5/4$ is achieved, because when $x = y = z = 7/4$, the minimum expression is $5/4$.

**Work**

One can restate the problem in terms of matrices, obviously.  This makes it easier to formalize the problem, but doesn't appear to me to generate much insight.

It seems that a trick like the one done in the example would work in many cases, but I have no idea how to prove it, and it seems unlikely that this would work in *all* cases.

The $\min$ function (from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$, for some $d$)
is continuous, but not differentiable.  Thus the standard method for finding the maximum of the function (Lagrange multipliers) does not apply.

If you know of any references where someone has worked on this or a related problem before, a point in that direction would be very helpful.  Otherwise, any ideas or work towards an algorithm are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can use [Linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). If you restrict to non-negative variables then you can restate your problem as

$$
\begin{align}
\text{maximize }&t \text{ subject to the conditions} \\
   t &\le x \\
   t &\le y \\
   t &\le z \\
   &\dots \\
   t &\le x+y+z-4 \\
   x &\ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0 
\end{align}
$$
There are several techniques to normalize and to allow negative values of the variables, and algorithms that solve this kind of problems very fast.